# sec_error_untrusted_issuer error when connecting gmail with proxy enabled

Tags: security, https, proxy, gmail, fiddler

When I have been trying to access gmail through browser and when proxy been enabled, I have been getting "sec_error_untrusted_issuer" and can't able to proceed further. I feel this is some security implementation by gmail to not to sniff it's requests & responses. am I right? or is there something that I have to configure in proxy (fiddler/open source tools).

Also, could you please let us know the details/background on this. and how to implement this type of security feature in applications.

Answer (score 0):

The error message in question simply means that the client has not been configured to trust the root certificate authority that issued the certificate it received.

One way this would happen, for instance, is if you enabled HTTPS decryption in Fiddler, but when prompted to configure Windows to trust the Fiddler Root Certificate, you chose `No`.